# How to setup personal build in CDT eclipse over linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I started using eclipse CDT over Linux for some college exercises.
I want the build function to compile without linking?
Can i have the build to be as simple as: gcc -c -Wall  ?

Thanks

Comment: what you are trying to do,please?

Comment: I want to compile it before being able to link it.
I want to code and build it as if i wrote: gcc -c -Wall file.c

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your project, go to properties, and then C++ Build, you can set the building command and other building settings... If that's that you wanted.